# Pairwise Lepage statistic between columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder how to compute pairwise Lepage statistic between columns on data like:

```
> cbind(v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10), v3=rnorm(10), v4=rnorm(10))
               v1          v2          v3          v4
 [1,] -2.47148729  0.61727115  1.28285770  0.72974010
 [2,]  0.42657513  0.77615280  1.88207246  0.41295301
 [3,] -0.32480814 -1.75461602 -0.16589154 -0.52731722
 [4,]  0.02760296 -2.08827618 -0.47176830 -0.17416765
 [5,] -0.52760532 -0.20514629  0.15589594 -0.54623986
 [6,] -0.47143259 -0.56666084 -1.35046101 -0.92754741
 [7,]  0.61071291 -1.65132215  1.61024187  0.83128254
 [8,] -0.17746888 -1.09887111 -0.32012303  0.69382341
 [9,] -0.38707069 -0.69628506  0.04597653  0.13479181
[10,]  0.52030680  1.11764587 -1.10243994 -0.83949756
```

I'm thinking of having something like:

```
     v1.v1 v1.v2 v1.v3 v1.v4   ... v4.v4
[1,]     0     1     2     5   ...     0
```

Like what `cor(x)` does when `x` is a matrix. I guess `dplyr` might be an answer? Or there is a multisample version `pLepage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using base R's sapply. Not familiar with LePage test in R, but using correlation and your example data:

```
rdmatrix <- cbind(v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10), v3=rnorm(10), v4=rnorm(10))
corrmatrix <- sapply(1:ncol(rdmatrix), 
                     function(x,y) cor(rdmatrix[,x], rdmatrix[,y]), 1:ncol(rdmatrix))

#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
# [1,]  1.0000000 -0.4613219 -0.5661391 -0.1703655
# [2,] -0.4613219  1.0000000  0.1965278  0.2111900
# [3,] -0.5661391  0.1965278  1.0000000 -0.3305471
# [4,] -0.1703655  0.2111900 -0.3305471  1.0000000
```

To flatten it out in a matrix of one row, consider the below using `outer()` for all combination set of column names and `do.call(cbind, ...)` to flatten:

```
# MATRIX OF ALL COLS PAIRINGS
cols <- outer(colnames(rdmatrix), colnames(rdmatrix),               
                      function(y,x) paste0(x, '.', y))   # NOTICE INVERSION OF X AND Y  
# FLATTEN COL NAMES
cols <- do.call(cbind, as.list(cols))                   

# FLATTEN CORR MATRIX DATA
finalmatrix <- do.call(cbind, as.list(corrmatrix))   
# NAME MATRIX COLUMNS
colnames(finalmatrix) <- cols[1,]                

#           v1.v1      v1.v2      v1.v3      v1.v4      
# [1,]          1 -0.4613219 -0.5661391 -0.1703655 
#           v2.v1      v2.v2      v2.v3      v2.v4
# [1,] -0.4613219          1  0.1965278    0.21119
#           v3.v1      v3.v2      v3.v3      v3.v4
# [1,] -0.5661391  0.1965278          1 -0.3305471
#           v4.v1      v4.v2      v4.v3      v4.v4
# [1,] -0.1703655    0.21119 -0.3305471          1
```

Comment: Great! Interesting question.

Comment: I just tried it with `pLepage()`, however it failed to generate a 4*4 matrix, but a vector of 4 values.

Comment: What is your input? You must be returning the list of [pLepage()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/NSM3/docs/pLepage): m, n, obs.stat, p.val? Try selecting one in `sapply()` function: `pLepage(x, y)$obs.stat`.

Comment: that's what I did, return `obs.stat` only.

Comment: I think `pLepage` works differently, I'm trying to use a self-define function to get `obs.stat` instead. Thank you.

Comment: To help, please update post with actual example code as `corr()` may not be structurally same as `pLepage()` especially in handling inputs.